# Why is the Standard model Higgs not a candidate of dark matter (in particular, a WIMP)?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, dark-matter, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model

Please consider me as a naive self-learner in this field.

The Standard Model (SM) Higgs boson is electrically neutral and has a mass of around $125$ GeV (which lies in the WIMP window i.e., between 10 GeV to 1TeV). *Why is then it is not a candidate of dark matter?*

1. Surely it can decay into SM fermions and gauge bosons. *But are we sure that the decay modes are not kinematically forbidden or insignificant so as to explain the present relic abundance*?
2. As I said that the Higgs boson mass lies in the WIMP mass window. How is it then different from a WIMP?

Comment: It may however decay into a dark matter particle that is stable. I believe this is a valid hypothesis. Atlas is actually experimenting on this hypothesis. But there was no update on the project since 2020. If you want to keep track of this project follow this link: https://atlas.cern/updates/briefing/probing-dark-matter-higgs-boson

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Higgs would quickly decay to a mix of products, many of them electrically charged. Thus dark matter is neither Higgs nor former Higgs.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance. Higgs boson is not present in the present Universe, only the Higgs field is. And it requires a particle collider to produce them. However, as I understand, dark matter particles are present in the halos of the galaxy. Is that correct? @J.G.

Comment: SRS, dark matter should be composed of particles with a long lifetime, or if it is short the only decays should be  in other weakly interacting particles. The Higgs is not a candidate because it decays fast to hadronic channels and also to gamma gamma. It will not have survived from the symmetry breaking time in the cosmological history.

Comment: @annav Can you give the theoretical expression for the decay width of Higgs to $\gamma\gamma$ and from that an order-of-magnitude estimate of its lifetime?

Comment: @SRS  it is not that simple. You can find how they give a limit in CMS data from the decay to four leptons in http://cds.cern.ch/record/2037207/files/arXiv:1507.06656.pdf  . the method is explained. The expected from theory lifetime is in femptoseconds.

Comment: @annav So if the Higgs Boson is so unstable how it can sustain an omnipresent Higgs field?

Comment: @Markoul11 The Higgs field is like a coordinate system all over space time, as all particle fields. The particle is what happens when a creation operator acts on a field, the electron on the electron field, the neutrino creation operator on the neutrino field etc. That is why since the Higgs field exists, people were waiting to see what the creator operator for the Higgs field would create, and the candidate was found in the cms and atlas experiments. stability has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @annav It may however decay into a dark matter particle that is stable. I believe this is a valid hypothesis. Atlas is actually experimenting on this hypothesis. But there was no update on the project since 2020. If you want to keep track of this project follow this link: https://atlas.cern/updates/briefing/probing-dark-matter-higgs-boson

Comment: @Markoul11 As my answer noted, if a large mass of Higgs bosons decayed, the products would be much more electromagnetically active.

Comment: @J.G. How are you so sure? Better watch the related seminar H--> invisible, https://cds.cern.ch/record/2715786?ln=en

Comment: @Markoul11 I'm sure because the _final_ decay products have to be protons, electrons & photons, with nothing before that long-lived.