# Why can't the Higgs vacuum energy clump to galaxies and act as dark matter (instead of dark energy)?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, galaxies, dark-energy, beyond-the-standard-model

The Higgs field has a nonzero vacuum expectation value which contributes to the energy density of the Universe. Energies contribute to the curvature of spacetime and affected by gravitational potential wells. Therefore, I have the following questions:

Why can't the Higgs vacuum energy clump to galaxies (the gravitational potential wells created by the galactic mass distribution) like dark matter do? Why isn't it more likely to found around the galaxies?

In other words, why can't the Higgs condensate be a candidate of dark matter(instead of a component of dark energy)?

**Note** Please understand that it is not a duplicate of my previous question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374738/why-is-the-standard-model-higgs-not-a-candidate-of-dark-matter-in-particular-a?noredirect=1&lq=1) which is related to Higgs boson, not the Higgs condensate density $v$, an energy density in space that can couple to gravity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the Standard model Higgs not a candidate of dark matter (in particular, a WIMP)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374738/why-is-the-standard-model-higgs-not-a-candidate-of-dark-matter-in-particular-a) (by OP), and [Is cold dark matter made of Higgs bosons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109991/84967).

Comment: The question is not why Higgs boson is not a dark matter. The question is why can't the Higgs condensate behave as dark matter. Please understand it's not a duplicate. @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: I don't see how those questions are different.

Comment: Why the *beyond-the-standard-model* tag?

Comment: @JohnRennie Well. Dark matter is supposed to be beyond SM.

Comment: The Higgs isn't though ...

Comment: Your question is unclear. The "Higgs condensate" is simply a name for the symmetry-breaking ground state in which the Higgs VEV is non-zero, it does not denote any actual substance that could "clump", "move" or otherwise be "found" anywhere.

Comment: I know what a VEV is, which is why your question does not make any sense to me: A VEV has no "location", so how could it "clump"?

Comment: VEV is like energy density. The question is "_if it is energy density why should it not concentrate around gravitational potential wells created by galaxies_?" @ACuriousMind

Answer (score 2):

The Higgs condensate should act like a vacuum energy i.e. a form of dark energy. If it gravitated it would would produce a dark energy around 50 orders of magnitude larger than the observed dark energy and the universe would have experienced a sufficiently rapid accelerating expansion that no macroscopic structures would ever have formed.

This is because the Higgs condensate is a fundamental property of space i.e. its energy density remains constant as space expands instead of diluting as space expands. This results in it producing a negative pressure which drives the expansion. By contrast normal and dark matter dilute as space expands and are normally considered pressureless.

Explaining this away is something of an embarrassment. Generally we assume that the Higgs condensate does not contribute to the stress-energy tensor for reasons that are unknown.

Comment: How does it differ from dark matter? @JohnRennie

Comment: @SRS I've extended my answer to address this

Comment: I know that dark energy doesn't dilute which is what observation tells. Right? But there is no reason why the condensate density shouldn't dilute. Is there? Also, I don't understand why you say "_Higgs condensate is a fundamental property of space_". As far as I understand, Higgs condensate the vacuum expectation value of the Higgs field, and therefore, a property of the Higgs field. Let us forget about dark energy. Why should the Higgs VEV not dilute with expansion? I'm trying to understand.

Comment: @SRS Unless the Higgs potential changes with time it will always produce a constant energy per cubic metre, regardless of how much or how little the universe has expanded. The expansion of the universe simply doesn't enter  the calculation at all.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. One more question. From what kind of observations we know that dark matter dilutes with expansion?

Comment: @SRS From the Planck 2013 analysis we know dark matter behaves like normal pressureless matter. Well, the models with dark matter behaving like normal pressureless matter fit the CMB data.

Comment: The Higgs condensate is not a substance, it is just a name for the ground state in which the VEV is non-zero, so there is nothing to explain away: A zero-point energy, i.e. an energy value for a state without any particles in it, is a perfectly fine contribution to dark energy that does not contribute to stress-energy.